# javaScript - Add key & value to Object

Tags: javascript, object

There is a forEach in my function for create Object:
Please Run code snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCntl', function($scope) {
  $scope.t = '';
   var input = "a,b,c,d,e,r \n1,1,1,1,1,1\n2,2,2,2,2,1 \n3,3,3,3,3,1";
  var rows = input.split('\n');
  var result = {
    header: [],
    body: []
  };

  //Get Header

  var headerString = rows[0].split(',');
  headerString.forEach(function(val) {
    result.header.push(val);
  });

  rows.splice(0, 1);
  rows.splice(rows.length - 1, rows.length); //delete "" row, from end array

  // Get Body 'a,b,c,d,...'
  rows.forEach(function(val, i) {
    var bodyString = val.split(',');
    var objBody = new Object;

    bodyString.forEach(function(val, i) {

      var strHeader = result.header[i];
      objBody[strHeader] = val;
    });

    result.body.push(objBody);
  });

  $scope.result = result.body;

  $scope.show = function() {
    console.log($scope.result)
    $scope.t = $scope.result;
  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntl">
  <button ng-click="show()">click me</button>
  <span ng-repeat="item in t">
   {{item}}
  </span>
</div>
```

And, this is objBody after forEach:

```
objBody = {   
    a: "1",  
    b: "1",  
    "c": "1"  
}
```

Now, my problem is  in **key with double qoutation** in last record of ***objBody***.
What is it? and Why?! > ("c")

[image]

Comment: What is inside `bodyString`?

Comment: your code has no output. What is that the result /of/?

Comment: And what is inside objectTmp ?

Comment: please don't give me Vote down.

Comment: What is inside `objectTmp`? Check if the 3rd element in `header` array inside `objectTmp` is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: "this is Result" — No, it isn't. The code in the question still doesn't include anything that would provide any output at all.

Comment: Well, now the code does include something that provides output, but it was added by Gilsha and doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Gilsha thanks, but your asnwer not show for me. please check again.

Comment: I just put your code as a snippet. The code has only one change, instead of `angluar.forEach` I used `array.forEach`. I think you may have noticed that there is no double quotes in the output obtained. Please do the necessary updates in the snippet to reproduce the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Your latest edit has the output `a b c d e r`. Still no quotes appearing.

Comment: Hey Guys, i try to edit my code snippet and that is correct. please check now code snippet. run that and check your console's log.

Comment: @Gilsha , Where are you?!

Comment: @Justinas thanks, solved my problem. please vote up me.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, solved my problem. please vote up me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved problem with split by regexExp:

```
var myRegex = new RegExp(/\s*\n/);
var rows = input.split(myRegex);
```

This command split every ' \n' in string. This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was arising due to the white space between `r` and `\n` in the input string. When you split the string by `\n`, the `rows[0]` will be  `"a,b,c,d,e,r "`. And after you split it with comma, then the last element will contain the white space like this `"r "`.

So just change the following line of code

```
var input = "a,b,c,d,e,r \n1,1,1,1,1,1\n2,2,2,2,2,1 \n3,3,3,3,3,1";
```

to

```
var input = "a,b,c,d,e,r\n1,1,1,1,1,1\n2,2,2,2,2,1\n3,3,3,3,3,1";
```

to fix the issue.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCntl', function($scope) {
  $scope.t = '';
   var input = "a,b,c,d,e,r \n1,1,1,1,1,1 \n2,2,2,2,2,1 \n3,3,3,3,3,1";
  input = input.replace(" ","");
  console.log(input);
  var rows = input.split('\n');
  var result = {
    header: [],
    body: []
  };

  //Get Header

  var headerString = rows[0].split(',');
  headerString.forEach(function(val) {
    result.header.push(val);
  });

  rows.splice(0, 1);
  rows.splice(rows.length - 1, rows.length); //delete "" row, from end array

  // Get Body 'a,b,c,d,...'
  rows.forEach(function(val, i) {
    var bodyString = val.split(',');
    var objBody = new Object;

    bodyString.forEach(function(val, i) {

      var strHeader = result.header[i];
      objBody[strHeader] = val;
    });

    result.body.push(objBody);
  });

  $scope.result = result.body;

  $scope.show = function() {
    console.log($scope.result)
    $scope.t = $scope.result;
  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntl">
  <button ng-click="show()">click me</button>
  <span ng-repeat="item in t">
   {{item}}
  </span>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** You have found some answer. But my way for removing white spaces from the dynamic input string would be

```
input = input.replace(" ","");
```

Comment: There is one problem, my input is dynamic and perhaps have many spaces.